# XSD Writing Formula based on User Selection

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XSD.
Trying to implement a Logic to generate a value.
In our XSD we have:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ChargeBandDescriptionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Less than or equal to one million pounds"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Greater than one million pounds"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Less than 5T EEE placed on market"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And another Element:

```
    <xs:element name="VATRegistered" type="xs:boolean"/>
```

So, depending on the selection- the Charge Amount and Band will be shown in the XML.
If [ChargeBandDescriptionType] 1 is selected while VAT as True- then £100, If B with No VAT then £30, and so on.

Is it possible to do? I have checked a lot on Google, couldn't find anything closer to it. Only I found I can write some built-in functions. Or [FieldName] * 123.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can't do that sort of logic in either XML or XSD, you can however have such logic in the application generating the XML for or if you are consuming the XML created by someone else you can program it in your application or use XSLT to calculate it.   If you are wanting to do it via XSLT then please give a sample XML file and your XSLT until now and explain your issue.

Comment: Thanks mate! Actually the client made me confused. He put that in the Requirements documentation. I knew this is possible in XSLT. Client later told me that they have the App to make that calculation. He wasted my time. Govt. Agency- slow response and don't know what they want.

Comment: Yes, sounds typical, don't know what they want, but want it delivered yesterday for a really cheap price :-)